# Need help forming mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Ok on my site I want it to be so when people visit http://mysite.com/201209041 it will redirect to http://mysite.com/[first 4 digits]/[next two digits]/[next two digits]/[all other digits]/index.html
so in my example it would redirect to http://mysite.com/2012/09/04/1/index.html
and in another example
http://mysite.com/20120904259872
would redirect to 
http://mysite.com/2012/09/04/259871/index.html

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you could split the url like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d*)$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/index.html [L,R]
```

In my opinion a PHP approach would be the better alternative though.

Comment: so something to where the rewrite would send it to mysite.com/index.php?=number

Comment: Hi mpeerman,
to clarify my answer: for this task the RewriteRules are likely to be much faster than PHP and if you only want this task to be fulfilled, stick to the mentioned solution. However, if you have more complex rules a php script might be worth thinking about.